# Programming in Vim: What specific mechanism do *you* use to 'copy-paste' variables?

Tags: vim, ide, editor, copy-paste

**NOTE**

This was flagged as a potentially subjective question, but it is not subjective. It is requested to learn the various *specific* ways that people use Vim so that a person coming from a "mouse-and-keyboard" oriented text editor might learn more of the Vim way of editing.

This is ***not*** a subjective question about ***personal preferences*** or which editor or editing style is best.

This is a specific question about the ***mechanical steps*** one would take to obtain an outcome in the Vim editor, using alternative editors as a baseline for cross-reference.

**PROBLEM**

Suppose you have the following code in your Vim and you want to get from *before* to *after* where before looks like this:

```
// Before //

$mynames    = Array();
$mynames['alice'] = 'alpha';
```

... and after looks like this ...

```
// After //

$mynames    = Array();
$mynames['alice'] = 'alpha';
$mynames['betty'] = 'bravo';
$mynames['cindy'] = 'charlie';
$mynames['deana'] = 'delta';
```

**HOW NON-VIM EDITORS WOULD DO IT**

Using a non-vim editor, programmer A would simply copy the first line for alice, paste it multiple times into the editor and then re-edit the values so that *alice* and *alpha* are replaced with the appropriate values, editing one line at a time.

Using a non-vim editor, programmer B would create a rectangular selection that spans four lines, and just start typing the common text *$mynames[''] = '';* and then go back and fill in the appropriate values, editing one line at a time.

**HOW ABOUT VIM?**

Given that Vim is a significantly different approach from "mouse-and-keyboard" style editors of the day, this is a request for insight on the specific steps one takes in editing with Vim. Obviously, it is possible to just type each line individually, but it is assumed that there is a time-saving way to do this in Vim in a way that compares to what programmer A and programmer B did above.

1) How would a vim programmer go about doing this edit operation, using a time-saving method like those above?

2) If someone were to search the Internet for more examples of specific 'step-by-step' comparisons of Vim editing sessions vs "mouse-and-keyboard" style editing, what would one search for?

Comment: Found another link: http://www.viemu.com/a-why-vi-vim.html

Comment: Take a look at [vimgolf](http://vimgolf.com/): people compete by trying to come up with the solution to text editing problems that require the less typing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use the same, first i copy a line. then pasting it any times what i need.

Then you can create a macro to edit a keys. When cursor is on first line where i need to work. (a frist pasted line)

```
    qq f[ci'<C>-<o>q  "recordes a macro to find a [block] and 
change inner quotes ' and stays in insert mode
```

Then you can play your macro any time by @q . (I have a map Q = @q for fast macro start by Shift+q)
The same way you can use for values:

```
 qq f=f'ci'<C>-<o>q
```

Macro for find a value block and go to insert mode.

And the answer for comparsion i will save time to move my hand from keyboard to mouse times = number of edit lines. Selecting a block for changing. Vim is more productive no doubt.

Answer (score 3):

If I know ahead of time what the different values are going to be, I'll to the roundabout approach. I'll start with this:

```
$mynames    = Array();
alice alpha
betty bravo 
cindy charlie
deana delta
```

Then I will place my cursor in front of alice, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, move down to `deana`, then hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to go into insert mode and type `$mynames['` followed by <kbd>Esc</kbd>. This inserts the text in all selected lines. Then I repeat that for `'] = '`, followed finally by `';'`

Not the most efficient way, but usually the first that comes to mind.

Comment: What is `Ctrl+R` here? Is it related to `Ctrl+V` for visual block mode? Because for my Vim it is the reverse of undo.

Comment: Good catch. That was supposed to be Ctrl+V. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I like AlexRus's solution (I love Vim macros).

But I think that a more realistic situation would be to paste the key/value pairs from some other application/document:

```
betty bravo
cindy charlie
deana delta
```

and perform a bunch of transformations on each line.

**SOLUTION 1**

We could select all three lines with `<S-v>jj` or some other way and apply a series of search/replace on the selection:

```
:'<,'>s/^/$mynames['
gv to reselect
:'<,'>s/ /'] = '
gv to reselect
:'<,'>s/$/';
```

The whole editing sequence looks like this:

```
<S-v>jj:s/^/$mynames['<CR>gv:s/ /'] = '<CR>gv:s/$/';<CR>
```

**SOLUTION 2**

We could apply a single search/replace

```
:'<,'>s/^\(.*\) \(.*\)$/$myname['\1'] = '\2';
```

where the search part isolates the beginning of the line (`^`), the space between words () and the end of the line (`$`) by actually matching the text between them and the replace part replaces the whole line with `$myname['` + the first match (`\1`) + `'] = '` + the second match (`\2`) + `';`.

I'm bad at regex so I had to check my notes to put it together but I have no doubt many Vim users are able to type that kind of command in one go. I will, someday.

The whole editing sequence looks like this:

```
<S-v>jj:s/^\(.*\) \(.*\)$/$myname['\1'] = '\2';<CR>
```

**SOLUTION 3**

With the same setup, we could enter *VISUAL-BLOCK* mode at the beginning of the first line with `<C-v>`, go as far down as necessary and type `I$myaccess['<Esc>` to obtain:

```
$mynames['betty bravo
$mynames['cindy charlie
$mynames['deana delta
```

move the cursor to the space between words with `f<Space>`, hit `<C-v>` again, expand the selection to the bottom and type `c'] = '<Esc>` to obtain:

```
$mynames['betty'] = 'bravo
$mynames['cindy'] = 'charlie
$mynames['deana'] = 'delta
```

then move to the end of the line with `$`, hit `<C-v>` again, select what you want again and type `A';<Esc>` for the last touch.

The whole editing sequence looks like this:

```
<C-v>jjI$myaccess['<Esc>f <C-v>jjc'] = '<Esc>$<C-v>jjA';<Esc>
```

Comment: yes, when i have only values or only keys i happy to use regular expressions